# Option key on MacBook Pro not behaving as expected

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

I honestly cannot understand what I've done over the past few hours or so but the Option key has suddenly just....stopped working how it should

Basically, UK versions of the MBP don't have a the hash/pound symbol explicitly displayed on the keyboard. To get it we simply press Option + 3 and it will print the symbol into your input field

except this has suddenly stopped working and I'm struggling to understand why. Options keys 1 - 5 no longer appear to do anything, whereas 6-0 and all the other character modifiers do appear to be working

Interestingly, I restarted the machine and I could type the symbols into the Login box fine, but after logging in it's stopped working again so I'm guessing I've somehow changed some user setting.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Check your keyboard layout in System Preferences (Language & Text).

Check the list of applications started when logging in (Accounts preference pane). It sounds like some third party hotkey utility/application launcher.

Comment: keyboard is set to british. Applications are GrowlHelperApp,iTunesHelper,Alfred,Dropbox

Comment: @djhworld Quit Alfred, press the keys. Does it work again?

Comment: Nope, no change. It just appears to be Option + 1 - 4 that are affected. 3 is the key where the hash symbol should render

Comment: @djhworld Are any other applications running in the Dock or the menu bar? Check the keyboard shortcuts assignments in the Keyboard preference pane. Create another user account (or use an existing one) and check to see if it works when logged in there. Did you install KeyRemapForMacbook (it's not just for Macbooks) or something like that?

Comment: Quit all applications in dock - problem still exists

Comment: Added new user, logged in as new user, problem goes away and keys work fine

Comment: haven't installed any key remapping stuff

Comment: @djhworld Check keyboard shortcut assignments in system preferences. What are the names of the files in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`, any possible relevant applications there? Do you have Spaces enabled, what are its keyboard shortcuts? How about Dashboard/Exposé keyboard shortcuts? Do you have third party preference panes installed, e.g. for Witch by Manytricks? Does the problem with the nonfunctioning keys occur in multiple applications? If you quit all possible applications (Alfred etc.) and enter `ps xc` in Terminal, what is its output? Quit as many of those you installed yourself as possible.

Comment: I've changed my keyboard layout to US and now the 1,2,5,6,7,8,9 keys have started responding. 3 and 4 still unavailable. Can't see anything in that folder that would affect anything, haven't installed any third party preference panes. Seems to occur everywhere.

Comment: I really cannot understand what I've done, this has been working fine for months.

Comment: I've restored all keyboard settings in the keyboard shortcuts preferences to 'default' and alt + 3,4 are still not doing anything

Comment: @djhworld Alt-1 and Alt-2 work now? Does it fail to work with both right and left alt keys? Does it work when you additionally press Shift to get ‹ and › on the British layout?

Comment: Pressing shift + alt + 3/4 results in ‹‹‹ and ›››› so that's working okay. Alt + 3 and 4 alone still don't appear to be doing anything

Comment: @djhworld If you're still able to, restore all your preferences except `com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist` and see if that's the responsible one.

Comment: @djhworld Just to be on the safe side, `com.apple.loginitems.plist` might also be possible. You can also temporarily rename the `ByHost` directory and see if a preference in there is responsible.

Answer (score 0):

I've asked elsewhere on the Apple discussion forums and they were equally stumped by this

The only 'solution' (as such) was to delete ALL .plist files under ~/Home/Library/Preferences

While it's not an ideal solution, it definitely got my keys working again

Comment: Have you *really* done this already? Resetting all your applications' preferences?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by checking Input Sources under System Preferences > Language & Text. I unchecked the box for "Unicode Hex Input" and "Keyboard & Character Viewer."  Hope this helps someone.